# Set width of div to the 'display width' of a div with no width property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm using ng-model to bind the value of an input to the content of `.one`. I've got `.one` set up with absolute position and no width set, so that `.one` will expand horizontally to fit content. This all works fine.

Now what I'd like to do is to set the width of `.two` to be equal to the width of `.one` so that the width of `.two` will change as content is added to `.one`

The following won't work, I believe because `.one` has no width property:

```
var x = $(".one").width()

$(".two").css("width", x + "px")
```

Is it possible to get the width of `.one` as it is displayed, and not based on it's CSS width property?

Check it out: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oez0488h/42/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the update to the keyup event on the input box.

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
    // Get the width of .one
    var oneWidth = $(".one").width();
    // Set the width of .two to the value stored in oneWidth
    $(".two").width(oneWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directive `ngKeyUp`

> ```
>   <input ng-model="text" ng-keyup="update()" />
> ```

that's the right way to bind a **keyup** event in **angular**.

https://jsfiddle.net/alvarojoao/kstmua9e/1/

```js
var app = angular.module("turingApp", []);

app.controller("turingController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.update = function() {
    var oneWidth = $(".one").width();
    $(".two").width(oneWidth);
  };
}]);
```

```css
.one {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20px;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="turingApp" ng-controller="turingController">

  <input ng-model="text" ng-keyup="update()" />

  <div class="one">{{text}}</div>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div class="two"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: @snookieordie please check  my answer for your problem